# PHP MySQL Register Page not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, html, php-5.6

I'm making a simple website running off my rpi 3 and I had some trouble at my register page. First of all this is my current database (id is set to auto increment and name is users):

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | password |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | Owner    | idk      |
+----+----------+----------+
```

I tried typing Username: Owner Password:test and while it should output "This username is already in use." it did "Something went wrong!", and when i do test for username and password it gives the same output instead of creating an account.

register.php (main page):

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
   header("Location: welcome.php", true);
}
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $rusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['un']);
    $rypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pw']);

    $sql1 = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$rusername'";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) values($rusername, $rpassword)";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 0){
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql2)) {
            echo "Account created successfully!";
        } else {
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
    } else {
        $error = "This username is already in use.";
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="topbar.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        //Top Bar
        <div class="topbar">
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            <a href="login.php">Login</a>
            <a href="register.php">Register</a>
            <a href="about.php">About</a>
        </div>

        //Register Form
        <div align="center">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form method="post">
                <h4>Username</h4>
                <input type="text" name="run" required>
                <h4>Password</h4>
                <input type="text" name="rpw" required>
                <br><input type="submit">
            </form>
            <div style="color:#ff0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

connection.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "kellan22";
$databasename = "accounts";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $databasename);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: Check `$rypassword`; should be `$rpassword` to match your SQL insert query

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing user inputted data in the wrong way. Those `mysqli_real_escape_string(...)` statements should be like this:

```
$rusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['run']);
$rpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['rpw']);
```

Also, missing quotes in your `INSERT` query, that one should be like this:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `password`) values('$rusername', '$rpassword')";
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your queries are susceptible to SQL injection attack. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).